# Animate the rotation of an object to be parallel to velocity (three.js)

Tags: javascript, html, three.js

I am using three.js to have 3D objects that move around on a canvas.
I have an object `self`, which has these properties:

```
var self = {
mesh: ...,
velocity: ...
}
```

The `self.velocity` value is a 3D Vector that has the motion in each axis per frame (<1,0,0> would move the object on the x-axis 1 unit per frame).
My current goal is to be able to have the front of the object be facing parallel to the velocity vector (e.g. if the velocity is up, the object will face up).

I saw [another Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30175145/three-js-convert-mesh-velocity-to-mesh-rotation) that appeared to be what I might be looking for, but (A) I couldn't make sense of the answer, and (B) I want to be able to animate the change from the current rotation to the new one.

What I am looking for is a function `faceParallel()` that will animate the rotation of `self.mesh` (possibly using Tween.js) to be parallel to the Vector3 described by `self.velocity`.

I appreciate any input you would like to give. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

consider:

```
var aimP = new THREE.Vector3();
aimP.copy(self.mesh.position).add(self.velocity);
self.mesh.lookAt(aimP);
```

(efficiency note: try to avoid calling `new THREE.Vector3()` a lot. If you are going to call this a lot on a lot of objects, move the `new` to some outer scope)

Comment: Thank you for responding. I understand that that is how to face parallel to the velocity's direction. However, there is still one element that I am missing to be able to tween the transition: the Vector3 that the object is facing before the new facing. Is there a way to turn the current Euler or Quaternion rotation to a Vector3?

Comment: `Vector3` has both `.applyEuler()` and `.applyQuaternion()` methods. Usage is pretty simple, e.g. `var ve = new THREE.Vector3(0,0,-1).applyEuler(someEuler);`