# THREE.js - Synchronize velocity and rotation of object

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have a collada model that I would like to orient itself in such a way that it points in the direction it is moving.

I have tried the approach outlined in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30175145/three-js-convert-mesh-velocity-to-mesh-rotation), but it didn't work for my case. I have also tried using the lookAt method of the Oject3D class to get the orientation of my model right, but that didn't work, either.

```
//x, y z are position vectors; vx, vy, vz are velocity vectors
//So every iteration I check where the object will be the next iteration
//to get it point in that direction

//Approach number 1

obj.quaternion.setFromUnitVectors ( 
  new THREE.Vector3(x, y, z), 
  new THREE.Vector3(x + vx, y + vx, z + vz) 
);

//Approach number 2

obj.lookAt(new THREE.Vector3(x + vx, y + vx, z + vz));
```

Clearly I've missed something. Help needed!

Comment: What was wrong with the `.lookAt()` method? If the object is moving at a vector of `1, 3, -2`, performing `.lookAt(1, 3, -2)` will make it point in that direction. Are you sure your initial geometry is "looking forward" before applying any rotations?

Comment: @Marquizzo It is a blender model that I have exported in the collada format, so you could very well be correct. Is there a way to verify, with THREE.js, whether the geometry is looking forward or not, and if not, how could I correct the problem?

Comment: @Marquizzo Figured out how to verify if it's looking straight forward or not, and the answer is that it's not. Thanks for your help! If you write an answer I'll accept it. Now I just have to figure out how to get the blender model oriented in the right direction, but that's another matter.

Comment: Just render the loaded object with no rotations. If it's pointing towards `0, 0, 1` (directly along the z-axis), then it's correct. If it isn't, you could perform a one-time geometry rotation (performed on `Geometry or BufferGeometry`) https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/core/BufferGeometry.rotateX to get its orientation right.

Comment: Oh, thank you, that did indeed solve the problem (moving fast here :D)!

Comment: No problem! Blender is a Z-up environment, whereas Three.js is a Y-up environment, so it's possible that's where the problem stemmed from.